# Setting up grunt-contrib-sass with node-bourbon

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gruntjs, bourbon

I am trying to add bourbon as a dependency to a project where `grunt-contrib-sass` is used. [node-bourbon](https://npmjs.org/package/node-bourbon) has the following to say about grunt and Sass integration:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    dist: {
      options: {
        // THIS IS THE LINE I ADDED TO MY CONFIG
        includePaths: require('bourbon').includePaths,
        outputStyle: 'compressed'
      },
      files: {
        'path/to/output.css': 'path/to/input.scss'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

However, when running grunt I get the following error:

```
OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: --include-paths
```

This error appears with any array of paths given to `includePaths`, not just bourbon.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`node-bourbon` is using [`grunt-sass`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) rather than [`grunt-contrib-sass`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass). That's why the option isn't available and you get this error.

So either swap those two grunt tasks or replace `includePaths` with [`loadPath`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#loadpath). That's the equivalent option in `grunt-contrib-sass`.